# Regex extract everything except a pattern (string in quotes)

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like `input = "I really like "Game of Thrones"` (show in quotes) and I only want to extract `I really like` but I can't get the right regex to do this.
Something like this doesn't work `re.search(".*^(?!\".*\")", input)`.

I can do something like `re.sub('".*"','', input)` but I'm struggling to find the non-sub, extract using `re.search` method.

Comment: A simple approach: 1. Find all quoted substrings using a regex. 2. Replace these with the empty string.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/R5Edrk/6

Comment: Using re.search you could use  a negated character class and a positive lookahead `[^"]+(?= ")` https://regex101.com/r/b6WIb0/1 https://ideone.com/Dv2Alx

Comment: @Thefourthbird Very helpful!  What if the quoted show title can be *anywhere* in the string?

Comment: Is the example string correct or did you mean `input = 'I really like "Game of Thrones"'`? The negated character class matches 1+ times any char until the assertion what is on the right is a space followed by a double quote is true. If it has to be between double quotes, then this might be an option `[^"\r\n]+(?= "[^\r\n"]*")` https://regex101.com/r/keOYh1/1 The `\r` and `\n` are to not cross newlines.

Comment: Yes it's correct I should have been specific - the quoted show name can occur anywhere within the string.  For example, `input = 'I really like "Game of Thrones" blah blah', your regex assumes show is the last part of the sentence.  What if it's in the middle?

Comment: Would it be possible to print/join two capture groups? Something like: `print(re.findall('([^"]*)(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")((?<=").*$)', s))` where `s` is for example: "I really like "Game of Thrones", it is the best!".

Comment: @randomcat123x In that case using 2 capturing groups could be an option `([^"]*)"[^"]*"(.*$)`  https://regex101.com/r/PHHiwK/1 See https://ideone.com/fjCxZD

Comment: @TheFourthBird. Add as answer and I'll surely upvote. You made my attempt look like a joke haha

Comment: do you have exactly one quoted part?

Comment: @JvdV Our patterns have the same intent using 2 capturing groups. What you could omit in your pattern is the second `[^"]*` as that is already matched in the first capturing group. You can omit this part `(?<=")` as the double quote before is already matched so the assertion will always succeed. If that is what the OP is looking for, you could post the pattern.

Comment: Two capturing groups works too!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
input = 'I really like "Game of Thrones"'

output = re.sub('"[a-zA-z0-9 _\.]+"','',input)

print(output)
```

output:

```
I really like
```

Comment: As mentioned, I'm trying to learn how to do this without `re.sub` and using `re.search` to extract everything not in quotes.